# What user does cloud-config run as?

Tags: cloud-init

When spinning up an AWS or other cloud vendor instance, and using cloud-init to configure the host, what user do bash scripts that get called run as?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Building an instance with the following config:

```
#cloud-config
write_files:
  - path: /root/test.sh
    content: |
        #!/bin/bash
        set -x
        set -e
        whoami
runcmd:
  - bash /root/test.sh
```

I got an output of:

```
+ whoami
root
```

Ubuntu cloud-config runs as **root**.

Comment: Is it possible to set a custom user?

Comment: @RovshanMusayev runuser -l $USER -c "<COMMAND"

Comment: It seems to me like a hack, but not a native cloud-init feature. I am not only about running a command but also running whole cloud init including writing files with custom user

Comment: I'm not sure it is possible. However, if it is possible and someone knows how to do it, I would love to learn.

Comment: @RovshanMusayev As far as files go, you can write those files as root user, and after that `chown` them to whatever user you need to.